# Using LinkedIn API's in 2019

Tags: linkedin-api

Looking around it is currently unclear to me whether or not LinkedIn allows 100% usage of all their API's. I see many sources from as long ago as 2017 saying "not unless you're a partner" and sources from 2018 saying "they brought the feature back" but I can't seem to find it or rather: **they have 2-4 websites with their application creation and/or documentation and there is not a clear answer anywhere as to which one is the place with the current up-to-date documentations and application creation/approval**.

Has anyone in the past year developed with LinkedIn's API's and could they point me in the right direction?

Can I develop on a POC, e.g. something like http://localhost[insertport] or do I have to use a live website? (which would be dumb, but whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Every thing is written there if you need any other help then let me know 
but before asking any question read this link document carefully

Yes, you can use localhost for development